# PBKDF AES Encryption converting Java to python

Tags: python, java, encryption

I have a java code that does encryption decryption , but however there is some issue in getting derivedKEK.

In java it is done as

```
derivedKEK = PBKDF2(ENC_KEY, salt, dkLen=32, count=1000, prf=lambda p, s: HMAC.new(p, s, SHA512).digest())
```

The value I get is of length 32 and the data format is

```
b'K27\xd7\xfc\xbf\xd0d\xec\x8f\xe4\\\x02\x95:0zn\xaf\x8c\xca\xf9\xf8:^(\xf4)\x9b\xd2p\xb8'
```

When the original java code is used

```
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
    import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
    import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;

    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(ENC_KEY.toCharArray(), salt, 1000, 256);

    // derive a Key-Encrypting Key (KEK) based on password and other PBEKeySpec attributes
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
    SecretKey derivedKEK = keyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
```

When i sysout the derivedKEK.getEncoded, i get something in this format

```
'[B@5123a213'
```

as a byte object. Here also length is same 32 bytes. How to adjust the python code to get the same format of derived KEK as java

Comment: `[B@5123a213` is not the key, but essentially returns the hash code of the object, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29140403/9014097). In order to obtain the actual key in a meaningful representation, a binary-to-text encoding should be chosen, e.g. hex encoding: `HexFormat.of().formatHex(derivedKEK.getEncoded())`. In the Python code, hex encoding is possible, e.g. with `derivedKEK.hex()`.

Comment: BTW, if you are using the PBKDF2 implementation of PyCryptdome, it is more convenient (with respect to the HMAC specification) to simply use `derivedKEK = PBKDF2(ENC_KEY, salt, dkLen=32, count=1000, hmac_hash_module=SHA512)` (see [here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/protocol/kdf.html#pbkdf2)).